Given, $f(x,y)=\begin{cases} {\frac{xy}{|x|+|y|}} & {(x,y)\neq(0,0)} \\ {0} & {(x,y)=(0,0)} \end{cases} $, $f_x(x,x)=?$

Given, $f(x,y)=\begin{cases} {\dfrac{xy}{|x|+|y|}} & {(x,y)\neq(0,0)}
\\ {0} & {(x,y)=(0,0)} \end{cases}  $. What is the value of $f_x(x,x)$
for $x<0$?
$1)\dfrac14\qquad\qquad2)-\dfrac14\qquad\qquad3)\dfrac12\qquad\qquad4)-\dfrac12$

Here is what I have tried:
For $x<0$, we have,
$$f(x,x)=\dfrac{x^2}{2|x|}=\dfrac{x^2}{-2x}=-\dfrac{x}2$$
So, the derivative of $f(x,x)$ with respect to $x$ is equal to $-\dfrac12$.
However, the answer sheet says the second choice is the correct answer (i.e. $-\dfrac14$). I'm not sure what I am missing.

You computed $\frac{d}{dx}f(x,x)$, not $f_x(x,x)$. And the answer is indeed $-\frac{1}{4}$.

@Surb Oh thanks, now I see that I need to evaluate the partial derivative first and then assign $x$ to the variable $y$.

One tricky/confusing/misleading part of the notation is that in $f_x(x,x)$ the 3 $x$ don't stand for the same thing. As function arguments, they stand for some unknown real number. As the 'index' for $f$, it stands for "derive the following function to it's first variable". If the question asked for $f_x(t,t)$, which is exactly the same thing, it might have been more obvious that calculating $g(t):=f(t,t)$ and then differentiaing that expresssion is not what is wanted.

As user:Surb commented, you computed $\frac{d}{dx}f(x,x)$, not $f_x(x,x)$.
As you responded, you first need to evaluate the partial derivative and then let $y=x$.
So $f_x(x,y)=\dfrac{y \, |y|}{(|x|+|y|)^2}$ at least away from $(0,0)$
and so $f_x(x,x)=\dfrac{x \, |x|}{(|x|+|x|)^2}$, which is $\dfrac14$ when $x>0$ and is $-\dfrac14$ when $x<0$.
